# WPF/C#: Frame - how can I get notice of a new html page being loaded in?

Tags: html, wpf, hyperlink, frame

I have a frame in a WPF window that I'm using to load an html help file for viewing - it's on a network drive. In my html file, there are links to other html files in the same directory. When I load the html (bound property `source = htmlSource`), the Navigating event is fired for the frame. However, when I click a link on that page to another in the same directory, that event is not fired. I've tied into an OnTargetUpdated event, but that only fires on the first page as well. I'm using INotifyPropertyChanged for the bound property "source".

Basically, any link doesn't seem to do anything with the frame containing the HTML. It loads in fine and is viewable, just can't get notice of it happening so I can make a back button visible. The source still says it's the original file, despite showing the linked html.

It's kinda driving me nuts. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to mix into the Html world, but not enough.  If you are really looking for "Back" button functionality, you should just create a parent HTML page that has an inline Frame and then use JavaScript function to handle your back button functionality.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to go back into the html to write javascript for this when it seems like I should be able to handle this in the frame control. I see your point, but I'd much rather prefer to just have the pages as html independent of that kind of functionality. If I have to do it, then so be it. Thanks, though.